# How to enable only one instance of spring boot microservice to make a particular rest call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, load-balancing, multiple-instances

I've two instances of spring boot microservice and I want only one of them to make a particular rest call.

My first thought was to create a table and put lock which only one of the service can acquire but that is not wanted.

Is there any other way to achieve it , I cant add zookeeper or any new cache mechanism.

My first thought was to create a table and put lock which only one of the service can acquire but that is not wanted.

Comment: are you talking about two instances of the same microservice? If so you should just use the same mechanism you use to access to those services i.e. api gateway, load balancer etc. If you would like to secure data consistency because of parallel or repeated execution etc. the only way to do it is having a lock on the data layer

Comment: yes two instances of same service and I cannot use the data lock. My first thought was using lock.

Answer (score 0):

The instances of a Spring Boot application started by the load balancer will have either different host names (ip addresses) or at least different port numbers. You can read this values and make a decision about calling the particular rest call.

To read the current port number you can use this code:

```
@Service
public class ServerPortService {
    private int port;

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ServletWebServerInitializedEvent event) {
        port = event.getWebServer().getPort();
    }
}
```

Based on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-running-port

Comment: to make the decision both instances should be aware that only one has to make call, how to achieve that without lock.

Comment: As described in my answer. For example knowing that your instances have port numbers between 8080 and 8089 you can read the port number and make the call only if it is 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is using a lock in an external system. Though I don't think it is a good idea, you can use an external redis instance to manage the lock which would be a lot faster than using a relational db. But you can't fix the issue you described inside the application directly.